# Is Class an object, or is it a struct?

Tags: objective-c

Is `Class` an object, or is it a struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C classes are considered as objects, with a few restrictions (see [Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html)):

> Class objects are thus full-fledged
>   objects that can be dynamically typed,
>   receive messages, and inherit methods
>   from other classes. They’re special
>   only in that they’re created by the
>   compiler, lack data structures
>   (instance variables) of their own
>   other than those built from the class
>   definition, and are the agents for
>   producing instances at runtime.

Behind the scene, a class definition contains various kinds of information, much of it about instances of the class:

- The name of the class and its superclass
- A template describing a set of instance variables
- The declarations of method names and their return and argument types
- The method implementations

Answer (score 5):

Officially, it's implemented as a struct, but the Objective-C runtime let's you treat a Class as an object.  Cocoa with Love has a great article on [how classes and meta-classes work in Objective-C](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Class` types are reference-types and `struct` types are value types. Instances of class or struct types are called objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is a type that can hold the pointer to a class object (similar to how `id` is a type that can hold the pointer to any object). `Class` is not the name of a class (similar to how `id` is not the name of a class). The class of a class object is the metaclass of that class (will not go into that here). Class objects are first-class objects; and you can do the same things with them as regular objects. Calling a method on a class object calls a class method on that class (or some ancestor class); you can also call the instance methods of the class's root class on a class object.